# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed - this is due to characters like

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, parsing, oracle11g

I've built a SQL XML program which works fine for most records but falls over on just a few records because of the data.

How do I overcome the problem with unwanted characters. I'm generating an XML file from an SQL on a Oracle11g database but get the below message in a few records. One of the records shows a XML tag field title containing "ô9.96 + õ.99 P&H" see below output.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <AV-XML xmlns="http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML AV-XML.xsd">
 <Delivery>
  <supplierType>ADMIN-AGENCY</supplierType>
  <versionId>0.7</versionId>
  <creationDateTime>2016-04-19T13:47:57+0100</creationDateTime>
  <otherInformation>MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY</otherInformation>
</Delivery>
<Message>
<messageSequenceId>1</messageSequenceId>
<messageType>NEW</messageType>
<otherInformation>MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY</otherInformation>
<Production>
  <prodCategoryType>COMMERCIAL</prodCategoryType>
  <prodStatusType>SKELETON</prodStatusType>
  <prodActive>true</prodActive>
  <prodCueStatusType>NO</prodCueStatusType>
  <prodTvInhouse>Y</prodTvInhouse>
  <prodTotalDuration>PT3M</prodTotalDuration>
  <priorityValue>1</priorityValue>
  <prodTitle>
    <title>CLASSIC LOVE SONGS OF RN R</title>
    <titleType>ORIGINAL</titleType>
  </prodTitle>
  <prodTitle>
    <title>ô9.96 + õ.99 P&amp;H</title>
    <titleType>CAMPAIGN</titleType>
  </prodTitle>
  <prodId>
    <idType>SOCIETY-ID</idType>
    <id>75125334</id>
  </prodId>
  <prodId>
    <idType>CLOCKID</idType>
    <id>TMECSRL505180</id>
  </prodId>
  <prodAuthorizedIp>
    <LASTNAME>BACC</LASTNAME>
  </prodAuthorizedIp>
 </Production>
 </Message>
 </AV-XML>
```

When I try to open this up in firefox or IE I get the below message which directs me to the line were the error is. Which is the ô9.96 + õ.99 P&H above.

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file://///data2/data/Download/d7prdv1/prsrepreports  /test_error_1.xml
Line Number 26, Column 16:        <title>49.96 + �5.99 P&amp;H</title>
```

How do I get around this problem, should I replace the characters using the REPLACE Oracle function with something more acceptable?

Comment: I don't see a closing `<AV-XML/>` tag.

Comment: Please, show a code which produced this XML.

Comment: ruudvan Sorry I forgotten to format the post it has been included now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that nested REPLACE  statements are what you need. You will just need to know the ASCII codes for the characters you want to replace. You listed 'ô' and 'õ', so I worked with those.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php

```
create table monkey(
    string1 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
);

insert into monkey values ('ô9.96 + õ.99 P&H');

select ASCII('ô') from dual;
--50100

select ASCII('õ') from dual;
--50101

select string1, REPLACE(REPLACE(string1, chr(50101), ''), chr(50100), '') from monkey;
```

Or, simply:

```
select string1, REPLACE(REPLACE(string1, chr(ASCII('ô')), ''), chr(ASCII('õ')), '') from monkey;
```

Comment: The replace function worked, so thanks unningviolent

Answer (score 0):

The two characters can be escaped with `&ocirc;` and `&otilde;` or with the fitting dec or hex code. This depends on the reader...

Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin1_supplement.asp

Additionally you might try to change the encoding to UTF-16. At the moment your XML is set to UTF-8 and the two o-derivates are not included in the base set of characters...

I don't know how oracle handles this, but in SQL Server it's a big difference if you state unicode or not. The first call would throw an error (illegal characters), the second (look at the leading "N" and the UTF-16) would work:

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><title>ô9.96 + õ.99 P&amp;H</title></root>'; 
DECLARE @xml1 XML=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><root><title>ô9.96 + õ.99 P&amp;H</title></root>';
```